# Error on defining Applicative's <*> with record accessors: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ t -> t1

Tags: haskell, applicative

I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Foo a = Foo { field1 :: a, field2 :: a} deriving (Functor)

instance Applicative Foo where
  pure a = Foo a a
  f <*> a = Foo (r field1) (r field2)
    where r g = g f $ g a
```

I am getting the following errors in GHCi:

```
help.hs:8:23: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ t -> t1
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘g a’
      In the expression: g f $ g a
      In an equation for ‘r’: r g = g f $ g a
    • Relevant bindings include
        g :: Foo (a -> b) -> t -> t1 (bound at help.hs:8:13)
        r :: (Foo (a -> b) -> t -> t1) -> t1 (bound at help.hs:8:11)

help.hs:8:25: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a -> b’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          (<*>) :: forall a b. Foo (a -> b) -> Foo a -> Foo b
        at help.hs:7:5
      Expected type: Foo (a -> b)
        Actual type: Foo a
    • In the first argument of ‘g’, namely ‘a’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘g a’
      In the expression: g f $ g a
    • Relevant bindings include
        g :: Foo (a -> b) -> t -> t1 (bound at help.hs:8:13)
        r :: (Foo (a -> b) -> t -> t1) -> t1 (bound at help.hs:8:11)
        a :: Foo a (bound at help.hs:7:9)
        f :: Foo (a -> b) (bound at help.hs:7:3)
        (<*>) :: Foo (a -> b) -> Foo a -> Foo b (bound at help.hs:7:3)
```

How can I implement this applicative functor instance of Foo so that it compiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition

```
r g = g f $ g a
```

require `g` to be a polymorphic function -- GHC can not infer such a complex type.

You need to be more explicit in your types, if you really want your code to compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, DeriveFunctor, InstanceSigs, Rank2Types #-}
instance Applicative Foo where
  pure a = Foo a a
  (<*>) :: forall a b. Foo (a->b) -> Foo a -> Foo b
  f <*> a = Foo (r field1) (r field2)
     where
     r :: (forall t. Foo t -> t) ->  b
     r g = g f $ g a
```

Alternatively, one can use a more direct approach:

```
instance Applicative Foo where
  pure a = Foo a a
  (Foo f1 f2) <*> (Foo a1 a2) = Foo (f1 a1) (f2 a2)
```

Comment: I was trying something like this, and I couldn't get it to work even with InstanceSigs, RankNTypes, and ScopedTypeVariables, until I read your answer and added the `forall a b.` in the signature for `(<*>)`. Why is that one necessary? I am pretty inexperienced with RankNTypes, but I expected the `forall a b.` to be implicit there.

Comment: @amalloy This is, IMO, a mistake in the original definition of Haskell, where `let f :: a -> ... ; f = ... where g :: a -> ...` actually means `let f :: forall a1. a1 -> ... ; f = ... where g :: forall a2. a2 -> ...`. Yes, the innermost `a` is locally quantified, and has no relation with the outermost one. So spoke the Haskell Report. GHC currently does the same, except when using the non standard `forall a. ` where it can safely diverge from the standard without breaking standard-compliant code.

Comment: Thanks @chi !  Someone on freenode also gave me:

instance Applicative Foo where
pure a = Foo a a
f <*> a = Foo (field1 f $ field1 a) (field2 f $ field2 a)